# Do I need next() for a ResultSet with one row?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I have the following code

```
Statement stmt = SqlHelper.initializeDB();
String query = "SELECT status " + 
                "FROM books " + 
                "WHERE bookId = '" + bookId + "'";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
result = rs.getString(1);
rs.close();
SqlHelper.closeConnection();
```

Do I need to use rs.next()? I am sure there is only going to be one row of data because bookId must be unique in the table. But by default, the cursor of ResultSet starts before the first row so I'm not sure if I need next() or not.

Comment: If you had read the API documentation of [`ResultSet.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--), it would have answered your question. You could also have tried it.

Comment: I did read the API, which is indicated by the last sentence of my question.

Comment: The description in the API applies always, no exceptions. That you think there will only be one row does not matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you need `next()`

> A `ResultSet` object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row[...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)